# How to compute the column average of an array using only the positive entries in Python?

Tags: numpy, average, numpy-ndarray

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(3,3)
A[1,0] = -666
A[0,1] = -666
A[2,2] = -666
```

I have a matrix whose entries are all positive except that -666 represents a missing value or outlier. How can I compute column average and row average with positive entries only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude the negative value from the count in the average denominator, you can use [numpy.maximum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) to clip negative values before summing along the required dimension/axis, and divide by the count of non-negative values along such dimension/axis:

```
np.sum(np.maximum(A, 0), axis=0)/np.sum(A>0, axis=0)
```

On the other hand, if you want to count also the negative values in the denominator:

```py
np.mean(A*(A>0), axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for!